# Solving the differential equation: $f(x)yy'=(y')^2-0.5$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this equation:

$f(x)yy'=(y')^2-0.5$

I have already tried traditional methods...

Any ideas?

Comment: that's what i'm thinking

Comment: Is there a change of variables to transform this into a 4th order ODE?

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)^2-\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{2y^2},
$$
or
$$
\left(\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2y^2},
$$
or
$$
\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2y^2}}
$$
or
$$
y'=\frac{y}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\big(y\pm\sqrt{y^2+2}\big).
$$
Using now Separation of Variables the problem reduces to finding the integral
$$
\int\frac{dy}{y\pm\sqrt{y^2+2}}.
$$

Comment: Note the function $f(x)$. This is a solution for $f(x)=1$

Answer (score 1):

solving the quadratic gives
$$
y' = \frac12(y \pm \sqrt{y^2-1})
$$
which suggests the substitution $y=\cosh u$

Answer (score 1):

We have

\begin{align*}
&y y^\prime = (y^\prime)^2 - 0.5 \\
& (y^\prime)^2 - y y^\prime = 0.5 \\
& (y^\prime)^2 - y y^\prime + \frac{1}{4}y^2 = 0.5 + \frac{1}{4} y^2 \\
& \left(y^\prime - \frac{1}{2} y \right)^2 = 0.5 + \frac{1}{4} y^2 \\
& y^\prime  = \frac{1}{2} \left(y  \pm \sqrt{1 + y^2} \right)
\end{align*}

You can solve this implicity using separation of variables.

Comment: Note the function $f(x)$. This is a solution for $f(x)=1$

Answer (score 1):

If $y^\prime$ is large (compared to 1), neglect the -0.5 to get the approximate solution $y \sim \exp(\int dx\,f(x))$. If $y^\prime$ is small (compared to 1), neglect the ${y^\prime}^2$ on the RHS and solve.

Once you have an approximate solution, iterate. Or use it as a starting point to get a power series solution. A lot depends on what you know about $f(x)$ and about $y$ - a power series solution could be a good starting point if you have some idea of these two to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

i will rewrite the differential equation $f(x)yy^\prime = (y^\prime)^2 - 0.5$ as a quadratic equation $$ 2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 - 2f(x)y\frac{dy}{dx} - 1 = 0.$$
this gives us $$\frac{dy}{dx} = {yf(x) \pm \sqrt{f^2(x)y^2 + 2} \over 2}$$

now i am stuck. i need to know a little more about $\ f.$

i will have to think more about this. but i will leave it here for a while. if i don't get any idea how to proceed i will delete it later. in the mean time hints are welcome.